# Password hashing on .NET 2.0?

Tags: cryptography, .net-2.0

The server I'm working with only supports .NET 2.0. I have an application which works with user accounts and I want to hash the passwords for obvious reasons. Unfortunately, System.Security.Cryptography seems only to be supported on .NET 4.0.

What are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use System.Security.Cryptography, which has existed since .Net 1.0.

Specifically, you should use an iterated salted SHA512 hash.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I just don't know how to use MSDN. I saw ".NET 4.0 Framework", which was apparently just a pull-down menu rather than a label, and I thought it meant it was only .NET 4.0-supported. My bad!

Comment: @Jonathan: Actually, something like Bcrypt (or even more: scrypt) [would be better here](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/). (This page links to a .NET implementation, too.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you think it's only been around since 4.0... here's the link to the [.NET 2.0 MSDN System.Security.Cryptography Namespace page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography%28VS.80%29.aspx).

The difference is that there are classes in that namespace that did not exist in 2.0 (such as Aes)